# Create a summary view

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create view that displays revenue like below. (amusement park database)

I have 3 tables:
x_transaction (transaction_id, rides_id, amount, ...)
x_rides (rides_id, rides_category_id,...)

x_rides_category (rides_category_id, name, ...)

And I need to create a view that displays total revenue for each rides category

category    revenue
------------   -----------
sport          34000
water         27000
adrenaline 24300
adult          null

BTW sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `outer joins` and `group by` as following:

```
Create view your_view_name as
Select cat.name as category, sum(amount) as revenue
  From x_rides_category cat
  Left join x_rides r on cat.rides_category_id = r.rides_category_id
  Left join x_transaction t on r.rides_id = t.rides_id
Group by cat.name
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The following should produce what you're looking for:

```
CREATE VIEW RIDE_CATEGORY_REVENUE_VIEW AS
  SELECT c.NAME AS CATEGORY, SUM(t.AMOUNT) AS REVENUE
  FROM X_RIDES_CATEGORY c
  INNER JOIN X_RIDES r
    ON r.RIDES_CATEGORY_ID = c.RIDES_CATEGORY_ID
  INNER JOIN X_TRANSACTION t
    ON t.RIDES_ID = r.RIDES_ID
```

I question whether the name of the second field on X_TRANSACTION is RIDE_ID or RIDES_ID. The latter matches the corresponding field on X_RIDES, but I've used the first name as that's what you showed in your summary of the X_RIDES table.

Comment: Oh, yes, the second field should be RIDES_ID. Sorry for my mistake.